# 'E:The package linux-headers-3.5.0-54 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it. ' when upgrading the system

Tags: apt, upgrade

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, and I try to upgrade to 14.04.1 using the terminal using:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
SystemError: E:The package linux-headers-3.5.0-54 needs to be 
reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

How can I fix the error and go on with the upgrade?

Output for `sudo apt-get check`  is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-3.5.0-54 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Output for `sudo dpkg -C`

```
The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:
 linux-headers-3.5.0-54 (no description available)
```

Out put for `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20130213)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`? This will install all packages to the newest available while preventing from breaking any dependencies.

Comment: I have tried it, still the same resault, I aslo tried in root

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get -f install linux-headers-3.5.0-54`

Comment: @ryekayo sorry, it doesn't work either

Comment: Can you check that link:http://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download *and reinstall* the `linux-headers-3.5.0-54` package. The issue here is that the package is only available in precise, which your sources don't do reference anymore. For this I would recommend download manually the package instead of adding the precise repository and reinstalling the package using dpkg to then proceed to remove it and continue with your upgrade:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-lts-quantal/linux-headers-3.5.0-54_3.5.0-54.81~precise1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.5.0-54_3.5.0-54.81~precise1_all.deb
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.5.0-54
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

For all other cases a simple:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install package-name
```

should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I experimented this with Cosmic (Ubuntu 18.10) that has been removed and the linux generic kernel update was required but couldn't be found.

I was saved replacing all urls in source.list by "old-releases.ubuntu.com":

source.list

```
deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic main restricted
deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates main restricted
deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic universe
deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates universe
```

is now:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates universe
```

then I could run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Now I can upgrade to newer Ubuntu…

Comment: thanks, helped a lot now when I tried to upgrade one VM with Disco Dingo.